# Plotting heat matrix with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as following

```
AgeGroup, Price Spent
10-15, 22.0
10-15, 30.0
16-20, 45
21-35, 22
16-20, 30.0
```

And so on..

For each group, I am plotting a density plot as follows

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(len(df['age_group'].unique()), 1, figsize=(10,10))

    for age_group in df['age_group'].unique():
          sliced_df = age_group['age_group']== age_group
          ax.set_title("age_group=%s"%age_group)
          sliced_df.price.plot(kind='density', ax=ax)
```

This creates a density plot of price for each age group
Instead of this, I want to create a "heatmatrix" or color map..
Where my rows are age_group and then columns sort of indicate the density in each "bin"
how do i do this in pandas?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [Seaborn](http://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/heatmap_annotation.html) which makes all kinds of nice visualizations that play well with Pandas. This example annotates each bin, but that is not required, you can just plot color weights.